# redis-server run multiple times binds multiple listening sockets on the same port?

Tags: redis

On Windows Server 2019, under WSL I ran by mistake `redis-server` a 2nd time, and it didn't report a failure in binding the listening socket. Here's the output of `netstat`:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -ano | grep 6379 | grep LISTEN
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6379           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6379         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13292
  TCP    [::]:6379              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11080
  TCP    [::1]:6379             [::]:0                 LISTENING       13292
```

Two questions:

1. How is that even possible?
2. How can I select which instance to connect to using `redis-cli`?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I ran it a 3rd time just to check, and here's the `netstat` output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -ano | grep 6379 | grep LISTEN
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6379           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13916
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6379           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6379         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13292
  TCP    [::]:6379              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11080
  TCP    [::]:6379              [::]:0                 LISTENING       13916
  TCP    [::1]:6379             [::]:0                 LISTENING       13292
```

These are the process entries from task manager:
[image]

Comment: Use `netstat`'s `-o` argument to see the Process IDs

Comment: Updated the question, there  are two process ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the socket has the [SO_REUSEADDR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/so-reuseaddr) flag set, then multiple processes will be able to bind to a given port.

"*[Using `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse)*"

> #### Using `SO_REUSEADDR`
>
> The `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option allows a socket to forcibly bind to a port in use by another socket. The second socket calls setsockopt with the optname parameter set to `SO_REUSEADDR` and the optval parameter set to a boolean value of TRUE before calling bind on the same port as the original socket.

This is intended to allow services to share the load among a number of independent processes, and should only be used if the service is able to handle this correctly... Redis may well be among the services that support this (and enable it by default).

See [`net.c`](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/deps/hiredis/net.c#L108):

```c
static int redisSetReuseAddr(redisContext *c) {
    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(c->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
        __redisSetErrorFromErrno(c,REDIS_ERR_IO,NULL);
        redisNetClose(c);
        return REDIS_ERR;
    }
    return REDIS_OK;
}

static int redisCreateSocket(redisContext *c, int type) {
    redisFD s;
    if ((s = socket(type, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == REDIS_INVALID_FD) {
        __redisSetErrorFromErrno(c,REDIS_ERR_IO,NULL);
        return REDIS_ERR;
    }
    c->fd = s;
    if (type == AF_INET) {
        if (redisSetReuseAddr(c) == REDIS_ERR) {
            return REDIS_ERR;
        }
    }
    return REDIS_OK;
}
```

---

If you need to deremine which server you've connected to, you can use the Redis command [`INFO server`](https://redis.io/commands/info), and look for the `process_id` field.

Alternatively, you can use `netstat -ano` on Windows (`netstat -tnp` on Linux) to determine the server's PID for a give client port (not client PID though).

I don't believe that there is a simple OS-level method to determine this relationship.

---

If you have multiple server instances using different configuration and/or data for each, then you have a configuration error that *you* should rectify - i.e: don't run multiple services at once, or use a different port for each.

This isn't something that Redis is responsible for, much like choosing the listen port isn't something that Redis is responsible for.

Comment: When I use `redis-cli` it always connectes to the same one tho. Or does it? How can I tell where cli connected to? And what about the dump file?

Comment: The same what? Server process? That's possible, I don't believe there are any strict rules about how the requests are distributed (e.g: round-robin)

Comment: "_How can I tell where cli connected to?_" - There may be a way to [retrieve the Redis server's PID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274530/1347519), or you'll need to interrogate the server process to determine if a given client is connected... I don't think that will be a simple OS-level task.

Comment: When I use `redis-cli` and run `info Server` one of the variables is `process_id` and it is always `process_id:73` regardless of how many cli's I run in parallel... Also, what about `redis.conf` and the dump file? The other two instances use a different `redis.conf` file

Comment: I don't know what "_dump file_" you're referring to (no mention in your question)... if there are multiple server instances using different configuration and/or data, then you have a configuration error that you should rectify - i.e: don't run multiple services at once, or use a different port for each.

Comment: How can I disable this port reuse feature? I want any instance beyond the first to issue an error that the socket is already bound...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110652/discussion-between-aviad-p-and-attie).